# What is a good way to store object type in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, types

Imagine I have such class hierarchy:

```
Base
A : Base
B : Base
C : B
```

I want to be able to retrive a `string` type from `Base` object `(I need string, not enum)`. I want also to be able to compare object type to `A` type for example:

```
Object *object = new A();
if (object->type() == A::typename())
{
   //hooray!
}
```

For now I'm planing to add a static function to each class:

```
static string typename() {return "Different name for each class";}
```

and then I will have to reimplement `Base` function `virtual string type()` for every derived class:

```
A: virtual string type() {return typename();} //A::typename
B: virtual string type() {return typename();} //B::typename
...
```

I think such design looks ugly. Is there some better way to achieve my goal?

**Why I need this:**
I'm developing a game. There is a tile map. Each tile has an array of objects on it. Some objects can be placed over the others. So i want to check if it is allow to put the object at the specific tile. For example: if tile has object with type "pot" then the flower can be put there.

Comment: Are you aware of the `type_id` object? (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/type_info/)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ? If you want a specific behavior for each class implement a base method which will be overridden by each inheriting class and implement its specific behvior. Testing for "instance of" is not what OOP is about.

Comment: If you're in need of information regarding an object's type beyond what you know via the pointer or reference through which you are accessing it, your OOP design may need to be reviewed.

Comment: @giorashc: Please see me edit

Comment: Have a look at the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the same thing with `dynamic_cast`. Your classes are polymorphic anyway.

**Note** that this is at least a code smell. You shouldn't need to find the actual type of classes in a well-thought design. What underlying problem are you trying to solve?

Also, `typename` is a keyword in C++, you should name your method differently.

EDIT: A possible better solution for this would be to have a list of pairs of objects that can be stacked, and have virtual methods:

```
class Object
{
   virtual bool canStack(const std::string& baseObject) = 0;
};

class Flower
{
   virtual bool canStack(const std::string& baseObject)
   {
       if ( baseObject == "pot" ) 
           return true;
       return false;
   }
};
```

Now I see why you'd want the get name.

Comment: Luchian: I prefer to store string constants as constants actually. Also because there will be a lot of types in the game and i don't want to rely upon i don't make a mistake typing "pot"

Comment: @Andrew if you have a collection of admissible combinations, it will be a lot easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a comfortable way of doing this for days.
Here's how I did it finally. The solution is pragmatic, compiles fast and is portable and **works without RTTI**.
However it uses #define, which C++ folks try to avoid often.
Maybe someone can turn that code into one that uses templates, which I would also be interested in.

Basically, the pointer to a static method is used for comparison with the one returned by "other" object in "static bool IsTypeOf(_TypeCheckBase& other)" so as to provide a type-check.
In addition you can get the name of the object.

```
#define TYPE_CHECK_IMPL(T)  \
   static bool IsTypeOf(_TypeCheckBase& other) { \
                    return other.GetType() == (unsigned int)&IsTypeOf; } \
   virtual unsigned int GetType() { \
                    return (unsigned int)&IsTypeOf; } \
   public: virtual const string& GetTypeName() { \
                    static string typeName = #T; \
                    return typeName; }

#define TYPE_CHECK_DECL(T) \
   typedef T _TypeCheckBase;\
   TYPE_CHECK_IMPL(T)


class root
{
    public:
        TYPE_CHECK_DECL(root)
};

class A: public root
{
    public:
        TYPE_CHECK_IMPL(A)
};

class AA: public A
{
    public:
        TYPE_CHECK_IMPL(AA)
};

class B: public root
{
    public:
        TYPE_CHECK_IMPL(B)
};
```

No you can do the following:

```
inline void prn(std::string txt, bool val)
{
    cout << txt << ": " << (val ? "true":"false") << endl;
}

#define CMP(foo,bar)  prn(#foo "\tis type of " #bar " TypeName:\"" + bar.GetTypeName() + "\"", foo::IsTypeOf(bar));

int main(void)
{

    A a; AA aa;
    B b;

    cout << endl;

    CMP(A,a);
    CMP(AA,a);
    CMP(B,a);

    CMP(A,aa);
    CMP(AA,(*((A*)&aa)));
    CMP(B,aa);

    CMP(A,b);
    CMP(AA,b);
    CMP(B,b);
}
```

The main methods you use here are:

- bool Foo::IsTypeOf(bar) with Foo being a class type and bar being an object, derived directly or indirectly from your root class type.
- string bar.GetTypeName()